# emacs shell: how do i prevent many commands from automatically piping through a pager?

Tags: emacs

I'm using emacs-shell. I'm sick of typing various commands like `man` and `git diff` which use a pager without me telling it to. I think this is influencable by the shell and I want to turn it off so I can use emacs as the pager.

Comment: [PAGER](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Environment_Variables#PAGER)?

Answer (score 1):

Emacs have already a man mode just `M-x man` and you can use `magit` git mode for emacs. there is a [less](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellFunctions#toc11) implementation on emacswiki that can give you an idea for other pager based commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variable PAGER to cat:

```
 (setenv "PAGER" "cat")
```